# gmaps4rails - position from map

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, gmaps4rails

I am wondering how to get latitude & longitude information from a map using gmaps4rails and then store it in my db/model.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote about it [in the wiki](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Javascript-goodies)

Look at `Drop a marker and update fields attribute in a form` and take some inspiration.

Comment: I am having a problem with "$('#location_attributes_latitude').val(latLng.lat());" - my model is called "Thing" and it has 2 columns "longitude" and "latitude". When I change that line to "$('#thing_attributes_latitude').val(latLng.lat());" the latitude is not saved within the form. I can create a fake latitude by using a form <%= f.text_field :latitude %> and this will save. Any ideas?

Comment: thanks apneadving, but it seems that ,no matter what i call the adapted fields, nothing is saved. However my form seems to be working fine. Any ideas?

Comment: you should give me some details: validations errors? accessible attributes?

Comment: thanks for you help! I have a nested form for my model "Thing" which has attributes such as "entry", "latitude" & "longitude". So I have put your code inside my form and I have changed the fields to #thing_attributes_latitude. When I run the code, and use the gmap to set a marker to define a position (latitude/longitude), and hit "submit" on the form, only my "entry" attribute is saved to the model, and not the latitude & longitude. Any ideas?

Comment: shouldn't it be: `#thing_latitude` I guess you're simply misformatting your html and that's easily testable using your debugger

Comment: thank you so much for your help, will test it out now. Can you recommend how I could debug if the variables are being processed in the form - or to see if they are included as part of the form when I hit submit? Thanks!

Comment: Look at the params: the hash should match your attributes names

Comment: apneadiving thanks for you help but it appears that this doesn't working either. My form seems to work for other labels within my form, just not the javascript code for the maps / marker - updateFormLocation.

Comment: ahhh i feel so stupid! I didn't have the :latitude and :longitude fields within my form.... I thought the javascript created those fields. Thanks apneadiving! Works perfectly!